# How do I use 3dcart rest API

Tags: node.js, api

I need to get the last 10 days orders from 3cart rest API using nodejs. I read the API [document](http://apirest.3dcart.com/) but I couldn't figure out how to get the last 10 days orders.

Please give me your suggestions/ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you already created your application, saved your keys and made a successful API call so far?

Comment: yes, I have created the application and I have key and token. But I don't know how to call the rest API for last 10 days orders.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is the API call you want, however it does't have a `sort` or `orderby` parameter, which means you won't be able to get the last 10 orders.

http://apirest.3dcart.com/Help/Api/GET-3dCartWebAPI-v1-Orders-orderid_invoicenumber_orderstatus_datestart_dateend_limit_offset_countonly_lastupdatestart_lastupdateend

However it does have a count feature, which means there is a way to get the last 10 orders by doing a count of all the rows in the db and skipping them all -10.

example

it counts the orders

`[-------------------------] // <-- = 25`
the second call we skip the first 15 results and set the limit to 10.

`[---------------==========]` // <-- we take the last 10 orders

so we want to add the params `limit=10,offset=15`. The way you offset the results is by doing `25 - 10` or `totalCount - 10`.